# Sending data from custom adapter to activity

Tags: java, android

I have a custom adapter which has a delete button only. When I click on the 'delete' button, the adapter updates itself which means that I am able to pass the data between my custom adapter and the activity. When I add a new listview item, I increase my count which is a double data type and it's called 'myValue'.

However, when I click on the 'delete' button on the listview, I cannot manage to decrease 'myValue'. I am passing 'myValue' in my custom adapter as follows:

```
myAdapter = new myCustomAdapter(myValue, this);
```

and in myCustomAdapter, I decrement 'myValue' and call notifyDataSetChanged();
but it doesn't update 'myValue'.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: I can't tell based on your explanation, but it sounds like you're expecting `myValue` to be passed by reference, when it's actually being passed by value (since it's a value type).